# Можно ли автоматически удалять неиспользуемые таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте, постигаю базы данных и есть задача удалять таблицы если в них не было изменений, допустим за 3 часа, возможно ли это? если да, то как?

Comment: чисто ради интереса, зачем такое может понадобиться? о_О

Answer (score 0):

Назначение баз данных - накапливать и хранить данные. Для уничтожения данных служит шредер. ;)

Задачу можно разбить на отдельные элементы: удалить таблицу (есть такая команда в mysql), проверить наличие изменений за последние три часа (создавайте каждой таблице LastModify и проверяйте) и не хватит собственно механизма запуска по расписанию (crontab?), который вам нужно будет сделать вне mysql.

По идее в базах данных есть такие вещи, как триггеры на таблицу, но тут они не помогут, т.к. они срабатывают, когда активность появляется.

Также в других СУБД бывают встроенные механизмы заданий по времени, но в mysql пока такого не встроили.

Ну и ещё раз: сама затея - зряшная. Чисто разве в учебных целях для изучения механизмов подойдёт, но и то – лучше возьмитесь за какую-нибудь другую задачу.